# AMPscript - Lookup if data extension exists in Salesforce SFDC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, landing-page

I have a **form** that after being filled in creates a **data extension** record. Based on data from that form I would like to trigger automation that would take an **email provided in a form/DE**, and **check if a Contact/Person Account with that email address already exists in Sales Cloud**.

If the record **exists** in Sales Cloud - **update** it with fields from Data Extension.

If the record **doesn't exist** in Sales Cloud - **create** a new record based on data provided.

Is it possible with the use of **AMPscript** in **Automation Studio**? Or maybe there is some **other way** to do this?

Hubert

Answer (score 2):

There’s a much easier way to do this directly from the form.

You can use the code below to create a form on a CloudPgae that will capture basic info of the visitor, and upon submission, it will check if a person with this email address exists in Salesforce CRM.
If the person exists, their info will get updated. If not, a new lead will be created.
It also writes the details of the form submission into a DE.

```
%%[

IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true THEN



/* check if lead already exists */



  SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(

   "Lead",

   "Id,Email",

   "Email", "=", RequestParameter("email")

   )

  

  /* get lead id if lead exists */

  

  IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN 

  SET @leadId = Field(Row(@subscriberRows, 1), "Id")

  

  /* update existing lead */

  SET @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(

      "Lead", @leadId,

      "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),

      "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),

      "Company", RequestParameter("company")

     )

  
  /* add lead details to a DE */

  InsertData("DataExtensionName","LeadId", @leadId)

  ELSE

   /* create a new lead */

  SET @leadId = CreateSalesforceObject(

        "Lead", 4,

        "FirstName", RequestParameter("firstname"),

        "LastName", RequestParameter("lastname"),

        "Company", RequestParameter("company"),

        "Email", RequestParameter("email")

       )

  ENDIF       

]%% 

<h2>Thank you for submitting the form.</h2>



%%[ ELSE ]%%



<table style="padding: 20px;"><tr><td>

      <h2>Please fill in the form:</h2>

      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">

         <label>First name: </label><input type="text" name="firstname" required=""><br>

         <label>Last name: </label><input type="text" name="lastname" required=""><br>

         <label>Company: </label><input type="text" name="company" required=""><br>

         <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" required=""><br>

         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>

         <input type="submit" value="Submit">

      </form>  

</td></tr></table>



%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

You can adjust above script to your needs (to check and update/create a contact instead of a lead) or extend it if you need it to do more, eg. add the lead/contact to a Salesforce campaign or send them an email. Read more here: [Create a Sales Cloud-integrated lead capture form using AMPscript](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/)